# C++ compiler error: "Cannot convert std::list (*)() to std::list* in initialization"

Tags: c++, g++

Assuming the following code:

```
std::list<Test1> l1();
std::list<Test1> *pl1 = &l1;
```

The compiler gives an error (shortened a bit): **`Cannot convert std::list (*)() to std::list*`** in initialization

When l1 is initialized without the brackets, everything's fine. What is the issue here and how do I avoid it?

Comment: As far as I understand the error, l1() is actually interpreted as a method pointer. saying = std::list<Test1>(); fixes the issue. Why is the templated type treated differently?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the templates, it is the [Most Vexing Parse Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: @UnholySheep almost, most vexing parse is about function calls with temporaries.

Comment: @RyanHaining oh, I wasn't aware of that - is there a different name to describe the situation here (without temporaries)?

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not aware of one, but there likely is

Comment: @UnholySheep: No special name for it. It's just the "you declared a function instead of an object, whoops, read your book again" problem

Comment: @Zain: It's not treated "differently" and has nothing to do with templates. This happens for any type. Think about what happens when you declare a function `int foo();`

Answer (score 2):

As you have it written, `l1` is a **declaration of a function** taking no arguments and returning `std::list<Test1>`. Imagine if the names were different and this might be easier to swallow.

```
std::list<Test1> make_tests(); // cleary a function declaration, no?
std::list<Test1> l1(); // also a function declaration
std::list<Test1> l1; // can't be a function declaration, no ()
std::list<Test1> l1{}; // also can't be a function declaration
```

To address your comment:

```
std::list<Test1> l1 = std::list<Test1>();
```

fixes your issue because there is only one way to interpret it, which is as a variable declaration followed by assignment.

---

This tends to be especially hard to swallow, so let me put it in the context of a larger program:

```
std::list<Test1> make_tests(); // according to your rules, should be a variable

int main() {
    std::list<Test1> tests = make_tests();
}

std::list<Test1> make_tests() {
    // ... function body ...
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use `{}` if you are in `C++11` or later

```
std::list<Test1> l1{};
```

Comment: aaah because inline its still understood as a function declaration for the linker to link (?) gotcha :)

Comment: @Zain it doesn't reach the linker in your case, but had you called it then the linker would look for it yes

Comment: Thats what I meant, as in that is what would be the correct usage of such a declaration ^_^